# msb4018: the "createvirtualdirectory" task failed unexpectedly

Tags: btdf

While deploying Biztalk application I am getting below error:

\Program Files (x86)---- for BizTalk 1.0.0\1.0\Deployment\Framework\BizTalkDeploymentFramework.targets(1829,5): error MSB4018: The "CreateVirtualDirectory" task failed unexpectedly.\r
C:\Program Files (x86)-----for BizTalk 1.0.0\1.0\Deployment\Framework\BizTalkDeploymentFramework.targets(1829,5): error MSB4018: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80070003): The system cannot find the path specified.\r
C:\Program Files (x86)----- for BizTalk 1.0.0\1.0\Deployment\Framework\BizTalkDeploymentFramework.targets(1829,5): error MSB4018: \r

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"COMException (0x80070003): The system cannot find the path specified."

Since this is happening during app deployment via an MSI generated with the Deployment Framework, it appears that the physical folder for the virtual directory does not exist. Maybe it is not being packaged in the MSI at all, or maybe the location is different than the one specified in the .btdfproj.

I suggest you review the IIS sample application included with the Framework.

Comment: Hi Thomas
Thanks for answering!!

I checked BiztalkDeplyomentTargetFramework.target file and got below command to create virtual directory. I can able to see physical folder..

 <CreateVirtualDirectory MetabasePath="$(IISMetabasePath)" Name="%(VDirList.Vdir)" Path="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\%(VDirList.Physdir)" />

Comment: You shouldn't be using CreateVirtualDirectory directly. You should use the IISApp property. Please be sure to review the sample app [here](https://github.com/BTDF/DeploymentFramework/tree/master/src/btdf/Samples/BizTalk/IIS/IIS.Deployment).